# repopulate controls when validation fails in struts2

Tags: struts2

I am new this framework. In my page i have one dropdown and one text box. If any error comes that drop is no longer available. How to fix this.

Struts.xml:

```
 <action name="*DropDown"
            class="com.mmm.ehspreg2.web.action.DropdownListAction" method="{1}" />

<action name="addComment" method="add"
            class="com.mmm.ehspreg2.web.action.product.CommentAction">
            <result name="input" type="tiles">addComment</result>
            <result name="error" type="tiles">addComment</result>
            <result name="success" type="tiles">reloadList</result>
        </action>
```

Page:

```
<s:form action="addComment" method="POST">
    <s:action name="getDivisionsDropDown" id="actFetchDivisions" executeResult="true"></s:action>
    <s:action name="getPropretyTypesDropDown" id="actFetchPropretyTypes" executeResult="true" ></s:action>

<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3" width="100%" border="0">
                <tr>
                    <td class="error"><s:actionerror /><s:actionmessage /> <s:fielderror></s:fielderror></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="bdyRecords"><s:label>
                        <s:text name="common.division" />
                    </s:label></td>
                    <td class="bdyRecords" style="width: 1px">:</td>
                    <td class="bdyRecords"><s:if
                        test="#actFetchDivisions.lstEntities.size()>0">
                        <s:select cssClass="drop" list="#actFetchDivisions.lstEntities"
                            cssStyle="width:200px" tooltip="divisionName"
                            id="select_division" listKey="id" name="comment.divisionId"
                            listValue="value"></s:select>
                    </s:if></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="bdyRecords"><s:label>
                        <s:text name="common.propertytype" />
                    </s:label></td>
                    <td class="bdyRecords" style="width: 1px">:</td>
                    <td class="bdyRecords"><s:select cssClass="drop"
                        list="#actFetchPropretyTypes.lstEntities" cssStyle="width:200px"
                        tooltip="propertyTypeName" id="select_propertytype" listKey="id"
                        name="comment.propertyTypeId" listValue="value"></s:select></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="bdyRecords"><s:label>
                        <s:text name="common.comment" />
                    </s:label></td>
                    <td class="bdyRecords" style="width: 1px">:</td>
                    <td class="bdyRecords"><s:textfield name="comment.commentText"
                        key="common.comment" size="50" maxlength="60" cssClass="textbxadd" /></td>
                </tr>
            </table>

</s:form>
```

And validation enabled by CommentAction-validation.xml

Comment: Hi Jothi, 
Refer : http://struts.apache.org/release/2.0.x/docs/how-do-we-repopulate-controls-when-validation-fails.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've got a few options I can think of:

**Put dropdown List object in the session**

When you populate your dropdown in `DropdownListAction`, put a reference to it in the session.  That way, it will be available to you on your JSP if validation fails.  One final step to this solution would be cleaning it out of the session once `CommentAction` has executed successfully.

**Action Chaining**

You could use the [Chain Result type](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/chain-result.html) for your `input` result.  This would allow you to automatically invoke your DropdownListAction on validation errors.

```
<action name="addComment" method="add" class="com.mmm.ehspreg2.web.action.product.CommentAction">
   <result name="input" type="chain">addCommentDropDown</result>
   <result name="error" type="tiles">addComment</result>
   <result name="success" type="tiles">reloadList</result>
</action>
```

The catch is, this may mess up the population of your input fields.  You'd have to experiment with it.

Comment: Did you try the first scenario?   You may also be able to get it working using the Prepare interceptor: http://struts.apache.org/2.0.14/docs/prepare-interceptor.html

Comment: @Pat But in chain request how you handle validation message,

Comment: @PunitPatel that's a good point - you'd have to use something like the Message Store Interceptor to make sure your validation messages survived multiple HTTP requests: http://struts.apache.org/release/2.1.x/docs/message-store-interceptor.html

Comment: @Pat Message Store Interceptor also work for redirect action, so why use action chaining, struts2 documentation also not recommended it, Refer : http://struts.apache.org/release/2.1.x/docs/action-chaining.html

Answer (score 0):

I found the best way to resolve this.

Action should implement the ***ValidationErrorAware*** interface which involved overriding the ***actionErrorOccurred*** function.

You just paste the code needed, such as the Dropdown method in the example below, and return *INPUT* instead of *SUCCESS*.